# Why views does not increase when java opens the pages?

Tags: java, blogs

I have a code which uses tor every time to get a new IP address, and then it opens a blog page, but then also the views counter of the blog do not increases?

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.*;

public class test {

    public static void main (String args [])throws Exception {
         System.out.println (test.getData("http://checkip.amazonaws.com"));
         System.out.println (test.getData("***BLOG URL***"));

        }

            public static String getData(String ur) throws Exception {


                         String TOR_IP="127.0.0.1", TOR_PORT="9050";
                        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
                        System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", TOR_IP);
                        System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", TOR_PORT);

                URL url = new URL(ur);
               String s = "";
                URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
                c.connect();
                InputStream i = c.getInputStream();
                int j ;
                while ((j = i.read()) != -1) {
                    s+=(char)j;
                }
                return s;

            }

}
```

This I just made to understand what they have to pass this little auto script.

Comment: What technology is used to track page views? It is possible that the tracking mechanism is JavaScript based, so it would only be executed when JavaScript is actually parsed and executed, which doesn't happen with your approach.

Comment: Is the counter being updated with JavaScript?

Comment: I do not know but the most important thing is IP, what does js have, when it loads the page, which java did not have when loading that same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an evolving field, the blog sites try to detect and thwart cheating. Wordpress in particular excludes (https://en.support.wordpress.com/stats/):

> visits from browsers that do not execute javascript or load images

In other words just hitting the page doesn't count. You need to fetch all the resources and possibly execute the JavaScript as well.